# use uniqueidentifider as primary key

Tags: sql-server, database

Is it a good idea? would the use of it slow down my database compared to an integer field as primary key?

Comment: NO! Horrible idea - and YES! it **will** definitely slow your queries down - see my answer for more details and some helpful article links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUIDs may seem to be a natural choice for your primary key - and if you really must, you could probably argue to use it for the PRIMARY KEY of the table. What I'd strongly recommend **not to do** is use the GUID column as the **clustering key**, which SQL Server does by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.

You really need to keep two issues apart:

1) the **primary key** is a logical construct - one of the candidate keys that uniquely and reliably identifies every row in your table. This can be anything, really - an INT, a GUID, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.

2) the **clustering key** (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - INT or BIGINT as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seen massive performance gains when breaking up the previous GUID-based Primary / Clustered Key into two separate key - the primary (logical) key on the GUID, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate INT IDENTITY(1,1) column.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the Queen of Indexing - and others have stated a great many times - a GUID as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the GUID - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an INT with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a GUID as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using INT vs. GUID as Primary and Clustering Key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Lifted from [Coding Horror: IDs vs GUIDs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html)

### GUID Pros

- Unique across every table, every database, every server
- Allows easy merging of records from different databases
- Allows easy distribution of databases across multiple servers
- You can generate IDs anywhere, instead of having to roundtrip to the database
- Most replication scenarios require GUID columns anyway

### GUID Cons

- It is a whopping 4 times larger than the traditional 4-byte index value; this can have serious performance and storage implications if you're not careful
- Cumbersome to debug (where userid='{BAE7DF4-DDF-3RG-5TY3E3RF456AS10}')
- The generated GUIDs should be partially sequential for best performance (eg, newsequentialid() on SQL 2005) and to enable use of clustered indexes

Also of interest:

- SQL Server: [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=25862)

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of debate on this. If your db is all local (not disparate instances being replicated back into a master db) then I believe that increasing integers are the way to go. By default, Primary Keys are Clustered, so having a single, thin ever increasing number makes sense, because in the case of Unique Identifiers, you can cause index and table fragmentation because they are not ever-increasing. 
In my opinion, if you really need unique identifiers, make a separate column that is not the primary key but has a unique non clustered index over it.